# org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException even when the element is present

Tags: java, android, appium

I've 4 test cases defined using TestNG within my Appium project and all 4 test cases performs almost same code execution besides the difference that all 4 test cases run on different parts of the app I'm automating. The issue I'm facing is within my test case I need to find an element and get its value which works fine in Test Case 1 but fails for Test Case 2, 3 and 4 respectively. However if I comment out Test Case 1, then the code works fine for Test Case 2 but fails for Test Case 3 and 4. If I run code for Test Case 1, 2, 3 or 4 individually, all of them work. I'm not able to understand why the code works only for the first test case in execution but fails to find the element in the next test case.

Note that the only option for me to find element is using absolute xpath value since the app I'm trying to automate does not have any other attribute defined.

**Environment**
java client 4.1.2
Appium server version: v1.7.2
Selenium: v3.4.0
Desktop OS/version used to run Appium if necessary: Windows 10 x64
Mobile platform/version under test: Fire TV Stick running on Android 5.1.1
Real device or emulator/simulator: Real device

**Details**
I've provided the code for Test1 below. As mentioned earlier, Test2, Test3 and Test4 are same as Test1. The code below is the one which fails from second Test onwards even though the code works fine when tested individually and the element is definitely present on the screen when the code is executed. However the script returns no element found.

**Failing code**
strTime1 = driver.findElementByXPath("/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout[3]/android.widget.FrameLayout[3]/android.widget.FrameLayout[2]/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.TextView").getText();

**Code To Reproduce Issue**

```
@test //Test Case for Home tab
public void Test1_Home() throws InterruptedException, ParseException{
Thread.sleep(delay3); //Wait for 10 seconds to load the content
driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.FrameLayout[@content-desc="Home, Button"]").click(); //Code to click Home button
Thread.sleep(delay2); //Wait for 10 seconds to load the content
((AndroidDriver) driver).pressKeyCode(23); //Code to click first video thumbnail button
Thread.sleep(delay2); //Wait for 10 seconds to load the content
//Video pause verification code starts
((AndroidDriver) driver).pressKeyCode(23); //Pause the video
Thread.sleep(1000); //Wait for 1 seconds
strTime1 = driver.findElementByXPath("/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout[3]/android.widget.FrameLayout[3]/android.widget.FrameLayout[2]/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.TextView").getText();
System.out.println(strTime1);
Thread.sleep(delay1); //Wait for 5 seconds
strTime2 = driver.findElementByXPath("/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout[3]/android.widget.FrameLayout[3]/android.widget.FrameLayout[2]/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.TextView").getText();
System.out.println(strTime2);
time1 = time.parse(strTime1);
time2 = time.parse(strTime2);
System.out.println(time1);
System.out.println(time2);
if(String.valueOf(strTime1).equals(String.valueOf(strTime2)))
{
boolean result = true; //Set result to true
System.out.println("Home: Video playback pause successful");
Assert.assertTrue(result); //Passes the test case
}
else
{
boolean result = false; //Set result to false
System.out.println("Home: Video playback pause failed");
Assert.assertTrue(result); //Fails the test case
}
//Video pause verification code ends

Thread.sleep(delay2); //Allow the video to play for 10 seconds including buffering time
}
```

**Exception stack traces**

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 10.13 seconds
```

Let me know if any further information is required. Any kind of help would be appreciated

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/ --- You *also* have very bad error handling. Printing the exception message and continuing as-if nothing bad happened is not "handling" the exception.

Comment: I understand your concern but I'm not an expert programmer and hence have not handled a lot of things right now. I wanted to understand the reason which is causing the script to fail before I clean the code. I would probably remove the unwanted code so that you can help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

could you please try to locate the element with relative xpath or accesability id?
Also it is always best practice to use latest versions of appium server and java client as they are continuously making changes to the appium.
below is the link for latest java client if you are using maven : https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client

Comment: Hi Suraj, It is already mentioned above that I do not have any option besides absolute xpath as there are no attributes defined.